# Buying bitcoins with chinese RMB

Tags: exchanges

I know a Chinese citizens have a limit of 50 thousand dollars they can send abroad, yearly. I was wondering if it is possible to buy bitcoins in an exchange like btcchina and then sell them back in another exchange like bitstamp to receive cash in an European bank account. If it is possible, is there a limit ? Any regulation problem ?

Sorry if it has been answered already, but I couldn't find this specific thread.

Thank you.

Comment: If there's a restriction on how much money you can send overseas, I'm pretty sure that would be illegal.